# Ruby on Rails App crashing on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I have a Rails app working on my local computer, but when I push it to heroku, it crashes. The error log gives an error H10.
This is the log.
http://pastebin.com/6UqVW0BL
Can someone please help.

Comment: Please post your Gemfile

Comment: Can you post your config/environment.rb and config.ru

Comment: Gemfile : http://pastebin.com/dAFNTC7M

Comment: Environment.rb :http://pastebin.com/3zdCmimA  Config.ru:http://pastebin.com/DbT9Euba

Answer (score 0):

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes says an H10 error could be from "a crashed web process or a boot timeout". Is there anything that could be causing the app to take too long to boot up, i.e. doing a request across the net?

Comment: Nope. Not for the home page atleast. Also my code was working fine before I did a few css changes. later the old code wasn't working as well.

Answer (score 0):

In line 14 of that stack trace it says:

> n depend_on': No such file to load -- mysql (LoadError)

So it looks like somewhere it's trying to load mysql. Obviously, Heroku doesn't support mysql, only pg. And you are only loading the 'pg' gem in production, so somewhere in your project you are probably requiring mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to run `db:migrate` on heroku...